# Python - Handling broken URLs that are being passed into a redirect handler?

Tags: python

I have a text file with a couple thousand URLs in which I am trying to get all of the redirected URLs from.  So far I have achieved the ability to obtain the redirected URLs as long as the original URL does not redirect to a dead end or broken link with:

```
def get_redirect_url(url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler)
    request = opener.open(url)
    return request.url 
with open ('textFile.txt', 'r') as myFile:
    urls = [line.strip() for line in myFile]
    redirect_urls = [get_redirect_url(url) for url in urls]
    print redirect_urls
```

However, occasionally the program runs into a "page not found" or a completely blank page which causes the program to fail.  Is there a solution to handling these broken links by either erasing or simply bypassing them when approached by the program?  Cheers all. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your function to handle exceptions:

```
def get_redirect_url(url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler)
    try:
        request = opener.open(url)
        return request.url
    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
        pass # or do something
```

You'll get a `None` returned using the above where an exception occurs - so you may wish to filter those out, or otherwise ignore them in your list comp.